# Change a preference through a Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I want to change a preference in my class if the user selects 'OK' in an output dialog. For that I have implemented this method in my class:

```
if (basalcor != basal) {

                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    ChangeBasalDialog dialogo = new ChangeBasalDialog(basal);
                    dialogo.show(fragmentManager, "tagbasal");
                    if (dialogo.check == true) {
                        String ok= "Basal factor changed succesfully";
                        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myprefs.edit();
                        if (basalMorFrame == true) {
                            prefsEditor.putString("basalMor", String.valueOf(basal));
                            prefsEditor.commit();
                            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(Mymeasures.this, ok, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.show();
                        }   
                        if (basalNiFrame == true) {
                            prefsEditor.putString("basalNi",
                                    String.valueOf(basal));
                            prefsEditor.commit();
                            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(Mymeasures.this, ok, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.show();
                        }
                    }
                    }
```

And this is the class ChangeBasalDialog:

```
    public class ChangeBasalDialog extends DialogFragment{
     double basal=0;
     boolean check=false;
     @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

            builder.setMessage("The system recommends you now a new Basal factor ("+String.valueOf(basal)+"). Do you want to set the new one as default?")
            .setTitle("New Basal recommendation avaliable")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes, i want", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()  {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            check=true;
                            dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   })
            .setNegativeButton("No, I'll keep my old value", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   });

            return builder.create();
        }



     public ChangeBasalDialog (double a){
     basal=a;
     }
}
```

The problem is that dialogo.check is always false even if I press OK, and then I cannot change my preference ever. I just want to make it to return dialogo.check=true when I press the OK button but I've tried everything and I simply don't see it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do this:  `dialog.cancel();` you reset all the variables.

I would recommend you to use the Boolean check outside of the ChangeBasalDialog (if you have this ChangeBasalDialog inside another activity).

Or do implement a listener for your DialogFragment, [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html) is a well documented example.

Comment: Ok. I see the problem... but if dialog.cancel() reset everything where can I use boolean check? or what can I do to change the preference as I want... because it does not allow me to use methods like getSharedPreferences() in the class ChangeBasalDialog...

Comment: do you use this dialog just for your main class?

Comment: take a look at the updated answer, You can implement a listener for your Dialog, in the sample code you are going to receive a String but you can change it to receive a Boolean.

Comment: you can put your class `ChangeBasalDialog` inside your activity and put the `boolean check=false;` outside of your class. do you need any help with that?

Comment: in your activity , before the last } just copy and paste your ChangeBasalDialog class. Now you can put you boolean outside of your class and get the value like this `if (check == true) {
                        String ok= "Basal factor changed succesfully";`

if you need more help just chat with me and I you think that my answer is correct just check it as the answer.